# Are questions on how to find Requests for proposals in a specific area (country, continent, etc) appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am curious, as I'd like to ask the following question: "Where to find GIS related RFPs online for Canada?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**My reaction is no**, for two reasons:

(1) Localization in space and time.

(2) Such questions aren't really about GIS, but about the *business* of GIS.

I'm sympathetic about the overlap with GIS *per se* in #2, and have been glad to see some good threads here that are related to GIS business development, but I think that the appearance of transient threads solely seeking to develop business would cross the line into material that would, overall, be detrimental to the site.

An alternative question that *might* find a home here--but would still be pretty marginal, IMHO, could be something like "what methods do people use to identify/develop GIS consultancies/professional contacts/business opportunities?"  In this form, at least, the question would not immediately be closed for reason #1.

Comment: It's one of those questions, where I'd like to know the answer for, but not really sure where to ask it, whether on this site or others.

Comment: If someone were to ask a similar question, it would be beneficial to highlight prior efforts "I've tried looking at ..." and include one or more specific problems to be solved in the answer "...not only 'where' to look, but' how often', and 'how sizable' are such RFPs?"  -- although I'm uncertain if there will be any answers to such a question.